# Is one permitted to say good shabbos in the mikvah?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shemos-sacred-names, mikvah-ritual-bath

One might see a friend at the mikvah and wish to say hello and either being before or on shabbos wish him well.

Since shabbos is also considered one of G-d's names is it permitted to use this greeting at the mikvah?

Comment: Can you cite that Shabbos is considered one of God's names? (If so, why don't you write "shabb-s"?)

Comment: I've never heard of Shabbat being one of G-d's names. Are you sure you don't mean is it a problem to say "Shabbat Shalom" b/c "Shalom" is one of G-d's names?